# ClickOnce Deployment error at ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce

Good day,

I try to install a `c#` application (Demo.Printer.application) but keep hitting this error.

When I debug, I found that it stop at :

```
    Prompt("true, reach this step");
    Prompt("ApplicationDeployment is " + ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment);
    Prompt("ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri is " + ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri);

    string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
Prompt(queryString);
```

I can `Prompt` until the 3rd, but can not reach the `Prompt(queryString);` then hit error.
However, my third prompt is just show me "ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri is", it is print null, any Ideas?

Then straight prompt me my file has stopped working. Windows can check online for a solution to the problem...and so on.

My .net framework is 4.0. I tried to change to 2.0 but still hitting the same problem.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: Demo.printer.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5475746c
  Problem Signature 04: Demo.Printer
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5475746c
  Problem Signature 07: f1
  Problem Signature 08: 5b
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    17417
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Now the problem signature is `System.NullReferenceException`, how is it related to `System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (in the Tile)`? Seems the information before your edit is more relevant.

Comment: I change my question again. Kindly help.

Comment: You can rewrite the line so that it creates a local variable for each part (i.e. explode it by ".") so you can find the part which is null. aka loc1 = AD.CD; loc2 = loc1.AU; loc3 = loc2.Query;

Comment: @alik. Done separate it, and found it is hit error at last part.

Comment: have you enabled option **Allow URL parameters to be passed to application** in Publish options?

Comment: Yes, already enable by tick the check box.